# How to reload data from 5 DataGridViews saved in one String with end of DGV data markers

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net desktop application with 6 tabs. Each page on each tab has one DataGridView. Each DGV is populated from an associated text file. After loading the DGV from the text file some editing is performed on the DGV data. This event occurs approximately once per month, i.e., DGV2 populated with its text file in month two, etc. When populating the 3rd DGV with its text file, I would like to repopulate the 1st and 2nd DGV without having to reload from each original text file and reediting the DGV.
I believe I can save the data from each DGV in one string file with some kind of a marker at the end of each DGV's data. But what I don't know is how to begin reloading several DGVs from one string file. My proposed code would look something like what you see below.

None of the posts I have seen address loading data to multiple DGVs from one String file, nor do they address saving data from multiple DGVs to one string file.
I am a bit familiar with My.Settings for temporarily saving data but I don't think they would work in this application.

```
Using writeFile As New StreamWriter(addToFile)
 For x As Integer = 0 To Dgv1.Rows.Count-1
  For y As Integer = 0 To Dgv1.Columns.Count-1
    WriteFile.Write(Dgv1(y, x).Value)
      If y <> Dgv1.Columns.Count-1 Then
        WriteFile.Write(", ")
      End If
   Next
    WriteFile.WriteLine()
  Next
  Dim marker1 As String = "one"
 Repeat the above code for each DGV. 
End Using

For reloading
TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
  While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
    Dim seriesData As String() = TextFieldParser.ReadFields()
    Dgv1.Rows.Add(seriesData)
  Read marker1 and repeat for Dgv2...etc.
    Dgv2.Rows.Add(seriesData)
  End While
```

Comment: Does it have to be one file?  I'm assuming you are using different Datatables for your data source, can you just output it to an XML file very simply reload it with only a few lines of code

Comment: The sources are CSV text files created from another app. No, it does not have to be one file, however I thought it would be easier to load all of the DGVs from one file with separators/ markers. I don't know how to output to an XML file.

Comment: Ok, really will need to see a bit more about how you are loading your data, but as start.  I'm making a couple assumptions here.  That the data you are loading is being loaded into datatables that are members of a dataset.  If so, it is as simple as DataSet.WriteXml() and DataSet.ReadXml()

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I will show it in a day or two...I am out of time for the next couple of days. As I stated earlier A CSV text file, no datatable no dataset.